Enabling CORS not working in Next.js deploying on Vercel
I am trying to deploy a single-page app using Next.js on Vercel.
I have one POST and one GET request and it deploys but I'm not able to make any requests to the API. It keeps giving me this error:
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/api/' from origin [...] has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have added the code from the Vercel website on how to enable cors in both vercel.json and next.config.mjs and it still isn't working. (Source: https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-enable-cors)
My actual next.config.mjs:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  async headers() {
    return [
        {
            // matching all API routes
            source: "/api/:path*",
            headers: [
                { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
                { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" },
                { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT" },
                { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
};

export default nextConfig;

My actual vercel.json:
{
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/api/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "value": "GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I've also had them to where the value here { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" }, is "http://localhost:3000", it had no effect.
I have also changed the fetch url to an environment variable and used that, from some Stack Overflow threads, but still nothing.
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL = http://localhost:3000
My two fetch requests:
try {
      const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        cache: "no-store",
        body: JSON.stringify({ text }),
      })
      console.log('Successfully uploaded confession!: ', text);
      setSubmitted(!submitted);
      setText('');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error posting confession from home page:", error);
    }

const getConfessions = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/`);
    const confessions = await res.json();
    setConfessions(confessions.reverse());
    return confessions;
  }

Here is my repo on GitHub if it helps: https://github.com/letmeeatbrioche/confessions

Maybe try to use NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL instead. That should give you the correct host

@grekier Thank you, but that didn't work either.

Got to realizing that it was my fetch url that was causing the issue. I had it as "http://localhost:3000/api/", but when I changed it to the relative path "../api/", it worked.
